# ModX Evolution: Where is SMTP password stored?

Tags: modx, modx-evolution

I need to access password stored for SMTP mail account which emails are sent from.

More info:
http://www.webhostinghub.com/help/learn/modx/managing-modx/configure-smtp

In the admin panel password is masked with ********, so I need to know MySQL table name and column name for that setting.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The information is located in the table called `modx_system_settings` (assuming you kept the default `modx_` prefix).

In this table I suggest searching on `setting_name` for `%smtp%. It returns six rows on my installation.

The system setting keyword for the SMTP password is `smtppw`.